# Cannot import SQLite for SQLite Swift wrapper

Tags: ios, sqlite, import, xcode7, sqlite.swift

I followed the SQLite.Swift manual installation process exactly (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift), but a red warning appears at "import SQLite".

OSX (10.11.6)
XCode 7.3.1

**Question**

Do I need to create and include a header file?

**Reference info**

In SQLite.xcodeproj, libsqlite3.tbd is automatically linked instead of libsqlite3.dyslib.

[image]

Comment: Did you clean the project ? Can you expand the error?

Comment: thank you for the quick reply. How to clean the project? I created a new project and added the wrapper, which is all what I did. the error says "cannot load underlying module for `SQLite`" @Yuichiro

Comment: @Yuichiro Check my answer, and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

After following the SQLite.Swift manual installation process,
Select SQLite iOS from Product -> Scheme.  Now select Build from Product menu.

After waiting for Build succeeded, it does not show error for "import SQLite".

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in your project, the sqlite sub project is in your project folder. It needs to be its own separate folder.

When you drag and drop the sqlite sub project in, you need to make sure that all folders are collapsed, and put it at the bottom of all of the folders.

Comment: And no, you do not need to create a header file yourself.