# Installation error SQLite in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

I have a problem installing SQLite in my project on Xcode.

I followed the tutorial exactly on GitHub in Manual 
([Cannot import SQLite for SQLite Swift wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311605/cannot-import-sqlite-for-sqlite-swift-wrapper))

**Problem**: 
I have this error message that appears directly when I try to build my application. (Failed)

- Already clean the code, build the code
- Already handed over the files

My version: Xcode 9.2

[Linked Frameworks and Libraries Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nwIo.png)

[Error Message in Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJsgY.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48408951/how-to-correctly-add-sqlite-frameworks-to-the-xcode-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do under **Build Phases** is go to **Link Binaries with Libraries**, hit the add button and type in "sqlite" so you can select libsqlite3.

[image: Build Phase > Link Binary With Libraries]

Now use sqlite by importing it in swift files using

```
import SQLite3
```